# How to handle source not exist in audio video html5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onerror

How to handle source that not exist in audio video html5?

i tried https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/av_event_error.asp:
pure javascript

```
<audio controls onerror="alert(1);">
  <source src="http://somethingthatnotexist" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

with jquery

```
<audio controls ">
  <source src="http://somethingthatnotexist" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('audio').on('error', function(){
            alert(1);
        })
    });
</script>
```

but not solved yet.

the correct way to do this is only place property `src` inside `<video>` tag not inside `<source>` tag. like this:
works on both javascript and jquery

```
<audio id="myaudio" controls src="http://somethingthatnotexist"></audio>
```

But this looks akward for me, because:

1. i need provide more than 1 audio to my client
2. so many player plugins/library out there that use `<audio><source src=""></source></audio>` not `<audio src=""></audio>`

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<audio controls>
  <source id="my_audio" src="http://somethingthatnotexist" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

and

```
$("#my_audio").on("error", function (e) {
  alert("Error with source file!");
});
```

Comment: nice. thank you very much. i will update my question so your answer will looks clearly for everyone that meet same problem like me

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and common way is this:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://somethingthatnotexist" type="audio/mpeg">
  Error with source file!
</audio>
```

If the audio file can't be played for some reason, the included text will appear. (not in an alert, but instead of the player GUI)